# Affect of raw and diluted sodium on human

Tags: blood-pressure, food-safety, sodium, diluting

What is the affect of sodium on human if taken raw and if taken diluted . For example if I take 5g salt as raw and if I diluted the same with 1 liter water and consume will the effects on the body same or different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take 5 grams of salt without water, your kidneys will excrete the excessive sodium in order to maintain normal blood sodium levels. Since the kidneys can excrete sodium only together with water, you will also lose some water, which will probably lead into a slightly negative water balance.

If you take 5 grams of salt with 1 liter of water, your kidneys will excrete both the excessive sodium and water, but this will result in less negative water balance than taking salt alone.

If you continue to take excessive amount of sodium for several days, your body will adjust in the way that it will start to retain more water than before to help maintain normal blood sodium levels ([NIH.gov](https://www.nih.gov/news-events/nih-research-matters/how-body-regulates-salt-levels)).

In conclusion, you do not need to overthink what will happen after intake of different combinations of sodium and water. It is good to know that *excessive sodium intake* results in water retention, which, usually, does not have any health benefits.

Comment: Does blood pressure change ?

Comment: There should be no meaningful change in blood pressure after ingesting 5 grams of salt with or without water. In some people, who are "salt sensitive," long-term high sodium intake can result in increased blood pressure, though.